# jQuery Ajax Call and PHP $_POST['data']

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I would like to send some data by using jquery ajax function to my PHP file.

I have created such function:

```
function ajax_call (url, select, select_name)
{

    $(select).change(function () {
          $(".result").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"/>');            
          var select_value = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({        
              type: 'POST', 
              url: url, 
              data: { select_name : select_value }, 
                  success: function(data){  
                      $(".result").html(data); 
                  } 
              });
    });
}
```

I call it:

```
ajax_call ('url path to my PHP file', '#my_select_div', 'my_data_name');
```

I have problem with this part:

```
data: { select_name : select_value }
```

I would like to get:

```
$_POST['my_data_name']
```

but I'm getting:

```
$_POST['select_name']
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using object literal syntax, the key can be a string or an identifier. The identifier represents the key name, not a variable. You have to assign the key/value after creating the object if you want to use variable key names.

```
var data = {};
data[select_name] = select_value;
            $.ajax({        
              type: 'POST', 
              url: url, 
              data: data
```